# Approahces for accessing asmx - SOAP based APIs

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx

I have to use some APIs that are exposed via asmx-SOAP interface. One way to consuming these APIs I know of is by simply accessing these by adding a service reference in my project. I just haven't worked on using web service APIs in a long time and heard of many buzz words (like WCF) during this time. Are there any other and better approaches to using such APIs (then just adding a service reference)? If so, can you please provide pros and cons of those approaches?

Comment: why close sir? If its duplicate of any existing one, do you mind providing a link? If its a wrong forum for this question, do you mind letting me know where can I post this type of question?